# Shellscript does not read closing curly bracket

Tags: bash, shell

I have two files main.css and main_custom.css. I would like to find appropriate location in main.css with help of keyword and insert contents of main_custom.css at the identified location. I am trying to use shell script for the purpose. The code for each file looks like the following.

> main.css

```
[SOME_STUFF]
/*
==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
========================================================================== 
*/
[SOME_MORE_STUFF]
```

> main_custom.css

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

> script.sh

```
# Merge custom CSS into master CSS file
LINE_NO=0
while read LINE
do
    ((LINE_NO++))
    if [[ $LINE == *"Author"* ]]
    then
        read LINE
        ((LINE_NO++))
        if [[ $LINE == *"=="* ]]
        then
            read LINE
            ((LINE_NO++))
            break
        fi
    fi
done <"main.css"

# Merge custom CSS into master CSS file
while IFS= read -r CUSTOM_LINE
do
    sed -i -e "$LINE_NO i $CUSTOM_LINE" "main.css"
    ((LINE_NO++))
done <"main_custom.css"
```

The resulting file looks something like this --

> main.css

```
[SOME_STUFF]
/*
 ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== 
*/
body {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
[SOME_MORE_STUFF]
```

Now, when I execute the script, the script copies the first three lines of main_custom.css file but not the one with closing curly bracket. Additionally, I am also losing formatting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do either of the files have a trailing newline?

Comment: @Eris - main_custom.css does not have trailing newline. However, if I add that, `sed` complains with an error message `sed: -e expression #1, char 6: expected \ after 'a', 'c' or 'i'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sed oneliner alternative to your script - the closing brace must be on a newline

```
sed '/Author\x27s custom styles/{n; rmain_custom.css
}'
```

output for sample input

```
[SOME_STUFF]
/*
==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
==========================================================================
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
*/
[SOME_MORE_STUFF]
```